# Weighted least squares loss function in tensor_forest

Tags: random-forest

Does the Tensorflow random forest module (tensor_forest) allow to specify a true weighted least squares objective function to be minimized during the training of the random forest model?

From what I gather, random forest model training in tensor_forest occurs within a specific estimator (TensorForestEstimator), which does not seem to allow to specify a custom loss function (weighted least squares is the one I am interested).

How can I achieve this?